# Any reason not to add "Cache-Control: no-transform" header to every page?

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

We have recently fixed a nagging error on our website similar to the one described in [How to stop javascript injection from vodafone proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113268/how-to-stop-javascript-injection-from-vodafone-proxy) - basically, the Vodafone mobile network was vandalizing our pages in transit, making edits to the JavaScript which broke viewmodels.

Adding a "Cache-Control: no-transform" header to the page that was experiencing the problem fixed it, which is great.

However, we are concerned that as we do more client-side development using JavaScript MVP techniques, we may see it again.

Is there any reason not to add this header to every page served up by our site?

Are there any *useful* transformations that this will prevent? Or is it basically just similar examples of carriers making ham-fisted attempts to minify things and potentially breaking them in the process?

Comment: This can impact mobile devices, image compression and so on for 3G optimizations (french): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-Control#no-transform

Answer (score 16):

The reasons not to add this header is speed performance and data transfer.

Some proxy / CDN services encode the media, so if your client is behind proxy or are you using a CDN service, the client may get higher speed and spend littler data transfer. This header actually orders proxy / CDN - not to encode the media , and leave the data as is.

So, if you don't care about this, or your app not use many files like images or music, or you don't want any encoding on your traffic,  there is no reason not to do this (and the opposite, recommended to).

See the RFC here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.5

Comment: If the HTML page being served up had the `Cache-Control: no-transform` header, but any image files linked from it did *not*, would that allow proxies to transform the images? I'm assuming so.

Comment: You absolutely right. if you can and want serve only the html / javascript with this header, the other resources would allow encode by proxy.
it easy to achieve with `.htaccess`, you can define specific types of files to set their header.

Comment: It does make a big difference in case of images: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/mobile-isp-image-recompression/

Answer (score 12):

Google has recently incorporated the service googleweblight so if your pages has the "Cache-Control: no-transform" header directive you'll be opting-out from transcoding your page in case the connection comes from a mobile device with slow internet connection.

More info here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en

Comment: The key message from Google is you may be impacting SEO by adding this header: "Please note that pages that opt-out of being transcoded will be labeled in search results to indicate to users that they may take longer to load and may use more data."

Comment: Correct, it is also stated here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression

Comment: Please note that opting-out using `cache-control: no-transform` is not the only heuristic Google Bot looks for to decide if your web page shouldn't be transcoded. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en says: "Some pages are currently not transcoded, including video sites, pages that require cookies (such as personalized sites), and other websites that are technically challenging to transcode."