# Caching images in AngularJS (using md-virtual-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, angularjs-ng-repeat

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160518/caching-images-in-angularjs-ngrepeat), but this does not appear to apply for my circumstances.

I'm building an app using [Angular-Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/). I have tabular data of about 5,000 rows, and I'm loading them in to a virtual-repeat container.

If you're unfamiliar, in short this limits the displayed data to as many rows fit in the viewport, and dynamically loads in/out data as the user scrolls, dramatically decreasing the page load. It's fantastic! (I've gone from a ~30s load time to >1s)

However, I have a cell in each row that pulls in an image from Facebook, looking like:

```
 <div style="background-image:url(https://graph.facebook.com/120945717945722/picture?width=200&amp;height=200&amp)" class="avatar"></div>
```

When I scroll down the page these images load fine, but as they're removed from the DOM it seems that they're not cached; when I scroll up and down the repeated table, the images load from scratch again and again.

How can I ensure that they're downloaded once and then cached properly?

To clarify, each repeated item has a different image, but the image for each item doesn't change (they all come from the facebook avatar associated with a particular organisation).

Comment: Yoe need to check the cache header of those images request. Maybe Facebook not let the browser to store those images in cache. Also, is this happens in all broswers?

Comment: @MoshFeu When I check in Chrome's resources panel, I see hundreds of images loaded in there, so *something* is happening. Perhaps it's an issue with the actual rendering of the virtual repeat container? How would I check?

Comment: Check in the `network` tab. Click on one of the images and check the headers of the request. Check the expires header.

Comment: @MoshFeu In my very uninformed opinion the headers look fine? http://imgur.com/tJRLP5X.png

Comment: Maybe this is the reason. In the image's header `cache-control` there `no-transform`. Now, according [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134257/any-reason-not-to-add-cache-control-no-transform-header-to-every-page#answer-20197125), this value causes to resource to download slowly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems today that accessing the picture through the graph is a pointer to the "current" resource. So, the url in your style rule is a method to retrieve the current picture. The graph url is a no-cache url because it redirects to the current resource (i.e. it isn).

So, for the browser to cache it seems to be difficult without forcing an assumption that the image has not changed.

Depending on your situation, proxying the request through your app server would give you some cache control. You could forego the cache header manipulation and use the proxy in conjunction with Angular's [`$cacheFactory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) to keep those objects in memory during the state of the app or until you remove them from the [`Cache`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) you create. **Definitely use caution with caching into memory with the amount of data you can potentially have.**

Comment: I kinda get what you mean, but if you look at the comments on the OP you'll see that it appears like the images *are* being cached, any response to that?

Comment: It seems the images are being cached but the browser doesn't recognize that the image belongs to the redirect url in the inline styles. So the cached image belongs to the fbcdn.net url and not the facebook.com url. Browsers get freedom to handle this how they want so many times you have to bank on the original URL's policy, which in this case is telling the browser to revalidate.