# bmi_SafeAddOnload Automatically comes in webpage source

Tags: javascript, php, html, code-injection

I am having a php page where i am seeing bmi_SafeAddOnload javascript function automatically at the end of page.

I dont know what it is . where is it coming from  ? will it cause any issue ?

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
bmi_SafeAddOnload(bmi_load,"bmi_orig_img",0);//-->
</script>
```

Also, Please let me know , how to stop it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113268/how-to-stop-javascript-injection-from-vodafone-proxy

Comment: @GerbenJacobs: I already seen that. May i know why is it coming ? how come others can inject some script into my webpage

Comment: You are using Vodaphone mobile internet. They, just like T-Mobile, add a "service" so you can load websites faster (basically a proxy). I wrote about it here: http://www.gerbenjacobs.nl/t-mobile-traffic-through-edge-proxy/

Comment: yeah., i read. Is it anyhow harmful to my site ? is there possibility for that ?

Comment: No it's not. In fact, only you can see it. It has nothing to do with the website, but your internet provider.

Comment: it is from Vodafone.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably your ISP who injects it, but you can't know for sure, it might just as well be a man in the middle attack. Whoever and whatever it is, it might cause problems. If someone can inject stuff into your page others can too.

The best way to stop it would be to run your page over TLS(HTTPS) and thereby remove such problems.

You can by a certificate for use with TLS, proxy traffic with CloudFlare and enable TLS or wait for [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to launch and get a certificate for free.